# Toggle layers on print composition

Tags: qgis, cartography, layers, print-composer

I want to use QGIS to make several views of bold colors for one same map. I've been using the layers in order to keep one on top of another. How could i make a composition on the print composition where i toggle through layers in order to view the different layers I've built?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a simple setting to toggle layers through the _Print Composition_ although I could be mistaken as I barely ever used it. What I did was to toggle layers through QGIS and click _Refresh_ in the print composition. Hopefully others can advise about a possible solution.